# CloudFront No Longer works after modifying S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I originally created an S3 bucket with a cloudfont to display the html code in the bucket at the publicly hosted domain hosted. I deleted the contents of the S3 bucket and uploaded new files. The endpoint for the S3 bucket displays fine in the web. The hosted url no longer works, I get an 404 error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more details of your CloudFront distribution settings? I wrote this article explaining how Cloudfront and S3 works and how you can deploy React applications step by step! It might be useful for you.

Please have a look at: [Medium - How to deploy single page applications to Cloudfront](https://medium.com/@lucashfreitas1/full-tutorial-guide-deploy-manage-and-deal-with-cache-on-spas-angular-react-vue-using-aws-566394f4f41e)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my error. Instead of using the drop down menu for the orgin link I used the endpoint of the bucket. It works now.